# Is it possible to measure outside magnetic field from inside a car?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I know that I can detect a vehicle by using magnetic field. I can see obviously difference in signal when a vehicle pass. But I don't see that when measuring in a car.

Is it possible to measure outside magnetic field from inside a car? If possible, how could I extract that signal?

Comment: Inside of a car you are basically in a metal cage that can act like a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).  You might be able to couple the detector to the car's exterior and use the car as part of the detector (Note: this is a stream of thought guess).